# Training set issue

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, logistic-regression

I have been able to develop a short script written in R to use the SVM algorithm (with rtexttools) and radial kernel in order to make predictions. Even though it works with simple classification problems I'm having hard time to make it work with a real classification problem which the training-set has a Sparsity index of 99%.

I have just a single feature which has a variable length (let's say from 3 char up to 300 per entry). Maybe increasing my traing-set would help... Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a methods question, not a coding question, so please post it on Cross Validated instead of Stack Overflow.

Comment: you can maybe use stratified sampling?